# crash while building with ffmpeg and contrib in raspberry pi 3 model B(debian)

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, c++, build, ip-camera

- OpenCV => 3.3.0

  - Operating System / Platform => raspberry pi 3 model B(debian)
  - Compiler => UNIX Makefiles
  - Cmake-GUI => 3.6.2

https://pastebin.com/5VGHA92m (build output from terminal)

> [ 39%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
>   /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libx264.a(common.o): relocation
>   R_ARM_MOVW_ABS_NC against `a local symbol' can not be used when making
>   a shared object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/local/lib/libx264.a: error
>   adding symbols: Bad value collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:228: recipe
>   for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3.0' failed make[2]: ***
>   [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.3.0] Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4311:
>   recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all'
>   failed make[1]: ***
>   [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
>   Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 2

using opencv=3.3.0
opencv_contrib=3.3.0

before building I Unchecked:
BUILD_opencv_world,
BUILD_TBB,
WITH_TBB,
BUILD_opencv_python2,
BUILD_opencv_python3, 
WITH_MATLAB,
WITH_CUDA,
BUILD_opencv_dnn,
WITH_OPENGL,
WITH_QT

and Checked:
WITH_FFMPEG(Default)

I installed all libraries (mentioned in below link)
https://pastebin.com/vFkYzQ08 (prerequisite libraries before building)

I also tried remove all those libraries and building opencv source with ffmpeg and contrib (yet build crashes at 23% for opencv 3.4    and 39% for opencv 3.3)

Comment: Debian package manager doesn't install things to /usr/local/lib so you must have built this yourself. I'd remove the static version of libx264 (the .a) and only leave the shared version (.so). The shared version has to be fPIC already and will resolve the linking issue. If you haven't got a shared version, you should rebuild it to generate the shared version of the lib or install from apt.

Comment: [This could be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487520/how-to-fix-a-local-symbol-can-not-be-used-when-making-a-shared-object-error), but I do recommend following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/) guide. That's how I installed OpenCV on my Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is some conflict with x264 library  (you can install it later once you are done with `OpenCV` build), remove that library then install `gstreamer`

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0
```

Install dependencies from 
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/04/raspbian-stretch-install-opencv-3-python-on-your-raspberry-pi/

and

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=80601

Below is output from CMake

> General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.0-dev
>   =====================================
>    Version control:               3.4.0-307-g14089b1
>  
>    Platform:
>       Timestamp:      2018-02-06T06:30:15Z
>       Host:                        Linux 4.9.35-v7+ armv7l
>       CMake:                       3.6.2
>       CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
>       CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
>       Configuration:               Release
>  
>    CPU/HW features:
>       Baseline:
>         requested:                 DETECT
>         disabled:                  VFPV3 NEON
>  
>    C/C++:
>       Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
>       C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.9.2)
>       C++ flags (Release):   
>         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG 
>       C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG 
>       C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
>       C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
>       C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
>       Linker flags (Release):
>       Linker flags (Debug):
>       ccache:                      NO
>       Precompiled headers:         YES
>       Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
>       3rdparty dependencies:
>  
>    OpenCV modules:
>       To be built:                 calib3d core features2d flann highgui 
> imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo shape stitching superres ts
>   video 
> videoio videostab
>       Disabled:                    dnn java_bindings_generator js 
> python_bindings_generator world
>       Disabled by dependency:      -
>       Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec 
> cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect
>   
> cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3
>   viz
>       Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
>       Documentation:               NO
>       Non-free algorithms:         NO
>  
>    GUI: 
>       GTK+:                       YES (ver 3.14.5)
>         GThread :                  YES (ver 2.42.1)
>         GtkGlExt:                  NO
>       VTK support:                 NO
>
> Media I/O: 
>       ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
>       JPEG:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so (ver 80)
>       WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
>       PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
>       TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
>       JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
>       OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
>
> Video I/O:
>       DC1394:                      NO
>       FFMPEG:                      YES
>         avcodec:                   YES (ver 56.1.0)
>         avformat:                  YES (ver 56.1.0)
>         avutil:                    YES (ver 54.3.0)
>         swscale:                   YES (ver 3.0.0)
>         avresample:                YES (ver 2.1.0)
>       GStreamer:                   
>         base:                      YES (ver 1.4.4)
>         video:                     YES (ver 1.4.4)
>         app:                       YES (ver 1.4.4)
>         riff:                      YES (ver 1.4.4)
>         pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.4.4)
>       libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
>       v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
>       gPhoto2:                     NO
>  
>    Parallel framework:            pthreads
>  
>    Trace:                         YES (built-in)
>   
>    Other third-party libraries:
>       Lapack:                      NO
>       Eigen:                       NO
>       Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
>       Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
>  
>    OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
>       Include path:                /home/pi/OpenCV/Source/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
>       Link libraries:    Dynamic load
>  
>    Python (for build):    
>          
>    Install to:
>   /usr/local
>   -----------------------------------------------------------------
>  
>  Configuring done